# Discord bot coded with python IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

```
File "main.py", line 16
await message.channel.send ('Sample text')
                                          ^
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

> I was trying to make a discord bot and this came
> repl it!

Whole Code

```
   import discord
import os 
#discord client
client = discord.Client()
#event
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
#event register
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
    if message.content.startswith('$vrise'):
   await message.channel.send ('Text')
  
  client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: please update your post to include the code that generated this error so we can answer with clarity.

Comment: Pasted the whole code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated now that you posted your code, thanks for updating the question!

Your code had its indents off. Change it to this:

```
import discord
import os

# discord client
client = discord.Client()

# event
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

# event register
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$vrise'): # This was one indent to much
        await message.channel.send('Text')

    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Notice the if statements and how their indentation needs to match for its scope.

Comment: I am using Repl.it

Answer (score -1):

You should show a piece of code instead of just the error. But for a quick answer I think the error might come due to a mixed between space and tabs in your code. Check with your ide if you don't have space and tabs. You should chose one or the other even if space is recommended by PEP 8

Also remove the space before the "(" after send

Comment: Thanks. await message.channel.send ('Text') Is not well indented I think. It should be under the if mesage.content with 4 spaces. It seems to far left